# python/pyqt - Pass a CancelEvent to a C++ function

Tags: windows, winapi, events, pyqt, dism

I have a WinApi function with a `CancelEvent` parameter but I don't know what I have to pass there?

```
HRESULT WINAPI DismUnmountImage(
  _In_     PCWSTR                 MountPath,
  _In_     DWORD                  Flags,
  _In_opt_ HANDLE                 CancelEvent,
  _In_opt_ DISM_PROGRESS_CALLBACK Progress,
  _In_opt_ PVOID                  UserData
);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh824802(v=vs.85).aspx

I'm working with python 3.6 on Windows 10. The function is working properly, the progress dialog too. I used QProgressDialog widget to display progress state, I only have to implement the CancelEvent.
The reDefinition:

```
from ctypes import *
import win32con, win32api

def UnmountImage(self, MountPath, Flags=DISM_DISCARD_IMAGE, CancelEvent=None, Progress=None, UserData=None):
    self.hDism.DismUnmountImage.restype = HRESULT
    try:
        return self.hDism.DismUnmountImage(MountPath, Flags, CancelEvent, Progress, UserData)
    except OSError as e:
        print("DismUnmountImage failed: %s\nErrorCode: %s" % (e.strerror, e))
        return self.GetLastErrorMessage()
```

And the pyqt part:

```
def canceled(self):
    print("canceled")

@pyqtSlot(QVariant)
def unmount_image(self, json_data):
    dism_progress_callback = dism_manager.DISM_PROGRESS_CALLBACK(self.dism_progress_callback)
    data = json.loads(json_data)

    self.progdialog = QProgressDialog("", "Cancel", 0, 100, None)
    self.progdialog.setWindowTitle("Unmounting Image...")
    self.progdialog.setModal(True)
    self.progdialog.canceled.connect(self.canceled)
    self.progdialog.show()

    for image in data:
        dism_manager.UnmountImage(MountPath=image['MountPath'], Progress=dism_progress_callback, CancelEvent=self.progdialog.winId())
```

I tried to pass the handle of the qtWindow but I get an error message `..can't convert parameter 3..`. What does the function expect? A windows handle? I really have no idea and I'm not familar with C++.

Btw: The QProgressdialog is a window with a QProgress and a QButton. When I click on the Cancel button, my `def canceled(self):` method is emitted and the window will be closed for a second and then the progress continues.

**EDIT:**
After zett42 suggestions I came up with this:

```
DISM_CANCEl_EVENT = CreateEvent(None, False, False, None)
```

And:

```
def canceled(self):
    print("canceled")
    SetEvent(dism_manager.DISM_CANCEl_EVENT)

    ...
for image in data:
    dism_manager.UnmountImage(MountPath=image['MountPath'], Progress=dism_progress_callback, CancelEvent=dism_manager.DISM_CANCEl_EVENT)
```

I get this error message:
`ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 3`

Do you have any idea, what I am missing?

**EDIT2:**
I got it:

```
def canceled(self):
    self.progdialog.cancel()
    SetEvent(self.cancel_event)

self.cancel_event = dism_manager.DISM_CANCEl_EVENT.Detach()

for image in data:
    dism_manager.UnmountImage(MountPath=image['MountPath'], Progress=dism_progress_callback, CancelEvent=self.cancel_event)
```

The only problem I have: The cancelevent needs round about 2 seconds to be performed so that meanwhile the dism_progress_callback forces the window to popup again, although i called `self.progdialog.cancel()` which closes the window...hope you can follow me. Do you have any suggestions how i can control this?

---

**Solved:**
I got a final solution: I called `self.progdialog.canceled.disconnect()` before `self.progdialog.canceled.connect(self.dism_cancel_event)` to overwrite the canceled() signal and prevent the call of cancel().

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below instead of including it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The function expects the handle of an event object which can be created using the [`CreateEvent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396(v=vs.85).aspx) C API. In Python you may call [`win32event.CreateEvent()`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.2/pywin32/win32event__CreateEvent_meth.html).

In your function `def canceled(self)` you should call [`win32event.SetEvent(hEvent)`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.2/pywin32/win32event__SetEvent_meth.html) passing the handle of the event object you created for the `hEvent` parameter. This will request a cancellation of `UnmountImage()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I did follow your instructions and edited my post, but it seems that the `CancelEvent` parameter is still invalid. Maybe you habe any ideas?

Comment: @FalloutBoy I see you found a solution, but now you have a memory leak because `Detach()` releases ownership so the handle will no longer be closed. Instead you should use `DISM_CANCEl_EVENT.handle`.

Comment: Unfortunately `DISM_CANCEl_EVENT.handle` has the same effect. When I click on Cancel the window is closed, at this time my console is empty. After 2 seconds the window pops up again and the progress continues. After another 2 seconds the window closes again and in my console I get the notification message `...Progress get canceled...`. Do you have an idea how to keep the progress window be closed? ...I could do a video if this helps?

Comment: @FalloutBoy Why do you call `self.progdialog.cancel()`? If the cancellation takes 2 seconds, then the progress dialog should still be visible so the user can see that the program is still busy. I would just disable the cancel button. Close the progress dialog only when `dism_manager.UnmountImage()` returns, then you don't have these problems.

Comment: sorry you are right, but I currently found this: `void QProgressDialog::canceled() [signal] -> This signal is emitted when the cancel button is clicked. It is connected to the cancel() slot by default`...so when i click cancel button, `self.progdialog.cancel()` will be run automatically. I have to overwrite the `Cancel` behaviour or add a QPushbutton which looks like the cancel button but doesn't react like it. I tested `self.progdialog.setCancelButton(cancel_btn)` but it obviously has the same effect. Any ideas?

Comment: @FalloutBoy Sorry, I don't know much about PyQt. Other frameworks normally have a way to suppress default behaviour when handling an event. As your original question has been answered, I suggest to make this a new question with a MCVE that concentrates on `QProgressDialog` only.